# Parsing out number using Ruby regex

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a situation where I need to grab a large number from a string. The two cases I'm working with are:

1) when the number is made up of only numbers, like 265038960

2) When the number has a letter appended to it, like 69235M

I've been using the regex pattern

```
(\d.+)[A-Z]
```

This works for the second case and grabs '69235' without the 'M', but breaks on the first case where a letter is not found.

How can I use a condition within the regex to only parse out the number whether or not a letter is present at the end of the string?

Comment: Why not just use `/\d+/`? `s[/\d+/]`? Do you need to match only specific *strings* (and "pre-validate" them with regex)? Then, you need anchors anyway. Try `s[/\A(\d+)[A-Z]?\z/, 1]`. Or are you extracting these large digit chunks from even larger strings? Then use `s.scan(/\b(\d+)[A-Z]?\b/)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I assume the OP is trying to capture in the letter, if it's there.

Comment: Add a `?` after `[A-Z]`.

Comment: How does your input string look like and how are the numbers delimited? Furthermore, could you give some counterexamples, i.e. substrings containing digits and letters that you don't want to match?

Comment: If you just want the integer, recall `"69235M".to_i #=> 69235"`.

Answer (score 1):

```
(\d+[A-Z]?)       # capture any number of digits, together with 0 or 1 uppercase letter
```

It's not clear if you want to capture the letter or not. In the case you want to dispose of the letter:

```
(\d+)[A-Z]?       # capture any number of digits, followed by 0 or 1 uppercase letter
```

Look at [example](https://regex101.com/r/uLk2VX/1)